# Associate my custom feature to default publishing site template with FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation

Tags: publishing-site, feature-activation

I want to have an event receiver on site collection creation, but it is not available. So as an alternative way i think of writing a custom feature, and associating it with the default publishing site template.

Is that possible?

So that everytime a site collection instance is created (publishig site) my code will execute.

As a note: My aim is; i want to make some initial work when the site collection of my project is created: Like deleting the default coming Press Releases site. (These kind of things can be achieved with custom site definitions or web templates, but i don't want to create custom site definition)

Answer (score 0):

You can look at what this article is talking about [Here](http://jamesemann.wordpress.com/2011/05/21/sharepoint-site-creation-using-spwebprovisioningprovider/).

So one option is the `SpWebProvisioningProvider` where you could effect the provisioning of a site and call your code on the site being created directly.

Or you could use a feature stapler that activated you custom feature on site creation and have a feature receiver that gets called on activation, thus calling custom code each time a certain (or all) sites are created.